# Почему не применяется свойство max-width: 300px; к flex элементу?

Tags: html, css

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #28282A;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.item {
  background-color: #FFBB24;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  display: block;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" class="item">Ссылка</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему Вы думаете что оно не применяется? `max-width` устанавливает максимальную ширину элемента, что не так?

Comment: Почему такое заключение что `max-width: 300px;` не работает? Оно активно у элементов `.item`.

Comment: А почему тогда ширина элемента не 300px? И если убрать свойство display: flex; то ширина ссылки будет 300px?

Comment: А почему Вы так уверены что ширина должна быть 300px? Конкретно ширина там нигде не указана. Повесьте `width: 100%` на `item` и будет Вам ширина в 300px.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое)

Comment: `max-width` не разрешает ширину больше указанной, вот и все.